# Finding proofs on wikipedia

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm looking for the proofs on [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix#Properties) of unitary matrices. I can't find them on wikipedia, any suggestion on where to look?

Comment: Various linear algebra books would be a smart place to start.

Comment: There is an online textbook, Linear Algebra Done Wrong:  http://www.math.brown.edu/~treil/papers/LADW/LADW.html

Comment: there are three complicated properties : that $U$ unitary implies it is diagonalizable, it is equivalent to the spectral theorem : that its eigenspaces are orthogonal, and that $U = e^{iH}$ with $H$ self-adjoint, which one do you want to prove ?